# java autoboxing from int to java.lang.Long casting issue

Tags: java, autoboxing

I'm getting compilation error from trivial substraction

```
Long result;
int operand1 = 10;
int operand2 = 5;
result = operand1 - operand2;
```

from last line:
`incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long`

beside the fact that I believe it can be converted what's the best solution to this? Any of the following will compile, but it seems awkward

```
result = (long) operand1 - operand2;
result = (long) (operand1 - operand2);
result = new Long (operand1 - operand2);
result = Long.valueOf(operand1 - operand2);
```

Which one is best for performance ?

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask for suggestion to improve your code.

Comment: 2 and 4 are basically the same. I wouldn't be surprised if they produce the same bytecode.

Comment: 1 is almost the same as 2 and 4, but has slightly different semantics around overflow (the subtraction is done between longs, whereas in 2 and 4 it is between ints).

Comment: why not declare result variable as primitive long and keep calm?

Comment: I would love to stay with primitive long only, but I have to allow null in one case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the byte code generated by javac 1.8.0_66:

(`result` is allocated to slot 1, `operand1` is in slot 2, and `operand2` in slot 3)

Approach 1:

> result = (long) operand1 - operand2;

```
    5: iload_2
    6: i2l
    7: iload_3
    8: i2l
    9: lsub
   10: invokestatic  #2              // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
   13: astore_1
```

Approach 2:

> result = (long) (operand1 - operand2);

```
   14: iload_2
   15: iload_3
   16: isub
   17: i2l
   18: invokestatic  #2            // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
   21: astore_1
```

Approach 3:

> result = new Long (operand1 - operand2);

```
   22: new           #3            // class java/lang/Long
   25: dup
   26: iload_2
   27: iload_3
   28: isub
   29: i2l
   30: invokespecial #4            // Method java/lang/Long."<init>":(J)V
   33: astore_1
```

Approach 4:

> result = Long.valueOf(operand1 - operand2);

This produces the exact same bytecode as Approach 2. Omitted for brevity.

---

As you can see, all four approaches construct a new `Long` object, since `Long.valueOf()` will call `new Long()`
*(although `Long.valueOf()` caches `Long` objects for values between -128 and 127 (in at least Java 1.8.0_66). If the values are outside of that range, calling the constructor is actually a tiny bit faster since it bypasses the cache checks!).*

Approach 5:
If you're interested in speed, don't use autoboxing, but use primitive types. Here's the change:

> long result;  // not Long

and the original statement works without complaints from the compiler:

> result = operand1 - operand2;

```
   6: iload_3
   7: iload         4
   9: isub
  10: i2l
  11: lstore_1
```

As noted elsewhere on this page, there may be overflow issues: the ints are subtracted first, then converted to a long. It might be best to simply use `long` for all 3 types (which will skip the `i2l` above).

Answer (score 1):

First 2 lines are supposedly best for performance since you are not creating any objects. 'long' is a primitive data type while 'Long' is a wrapper class for long. Between the first two, I'd say that 2nd is a bit faster, since you do the subtraction on ints and then convert a single value to long, whereas in the 1st - you convert both values to long and then do the subtraction of longs which would be a bit slower.

Regarding the compilation issue - primitive types do convert automatically to a larger one, i.e. int would convert to long if you subtract them. However, if you assign a value of that int to a Long class object you'll get compilation error, since the automatic conversion will not happen, so you'll have to manually convert int primitive to long primitive or to Long object.

Comment: actually you can pass int into constructor with long argument

Comment: @andrii Yeah, sorry got carried away, now I've corrected my answer - hope that's closer to the reality now.

Answer (score 1):

2 and 4 are basically the same. I wouldn't be surprised if they produce the same bytecode.

1 is going to be pretty much the same as 2 and 4 performance-wise, but it might produce slightly different answers if the integer subtraction in 2 and 4 overflows.

- 1 is equivalent to `Long.valueOf((long) op1 - (long) op2)`
- 2 and 4 are equivalent to `Long.valueOf((long) (op1 - op2))`

The only one I would avoid is 3, because this *definitely* produces a new value, whereas the others *might* use a cached value, depending upon implementation of [`Long.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-):

> [`Long.valueOf`] returns a Long instance representing the specified long value. If a new Long instance is not required, **this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor** Long(long), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. Note that unlike the corresponding method in the Integer class, **this method is not required to cache values within a particular range**.

Comment: I would argue that 4th is same with 1 and 2. The static method Long.valueOf(long l) will create a new Long object if the value of the parameter is outside the cache interval -128 >= i >= 127

Comment: @SerjArdovic no, it won't necessarily cache, it just might. Read the Javadoc. But 1 is different because it is `(long) op1 - (long) op2`, not `(long) (op1 - op2)`.